# Using files in a subdirectory as a root path on Apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Is there a way to use a subdirectory as root path on Apache?

Must I use `.htaccess`?

But I can't find a redirect that works.

The only one was:

`RewriteRule ^(.*).htm$ app/$1.php [QSA,NC,L]`

In this case I need to change the extension.

If I try to use the same extension on the rule, it seems that Apache enters into recursion.

I want to use an address like: `http://localhost/myPrjFolder/customers.php` and in file system actually is: `{document.root}/myPrjFolder/app/customers.php`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well yes, your match also maches the output of your rewrite, try excluding slashes from the match:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)\.php$ app/$1.php [QSA,NC,L]
```

Or whatever extension, that should set you on the right track.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer, but it doesn't work in my case.

Comment: Perhaps if you explain why not, I can offer a solution

Comment: I changed the extension in the example I gave to use `php` in case that was your issue. It must be in a .htaccess file in 'myPrjFolder' for that exact rule to work.

Comment: sorry, what happens is that the rule has no effect on the path.

Comment: Did you try with the updated rule? The previous one was not for your exact problem, but was just an example for you to work with. The new one should now work as it is.

Comment: See my comment above about where to put it.

Comment: I found the error message, on {apache_path}/logs/error.log and shows this: script '{file_system_path_of_root_document}/test_redirect/index.php' not found or unable to stat

Comment: If found my mistake, I forgot this line on my .htaccess: RewriteEngine On

Comment: Great, glad you got it fixed :) You can upvote my answer now if you like, since you just made it over 15 reputation! Congrats. (using the up arrow to the left and top of my answer)